# How to transform tensors to numpy.ndarray in Keras?

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, tensorflow, keras

I have got a Tensorflow Tensor within Keras (< class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>) which needs to be transformed into a numpy.ndarray. 
Is there an easy solution to this task?

I did time-comsuming research via Google and trial/error. 
It seems that I have to use tensorflow sessions, but I don't wan't to use any tensorflow sessions, because using them I will receive errors like:

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating 
TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: TITAN X (Pascal), pci bus id: 0000:09:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:1) -> (device: 1, name: TITAN X (Pascal), pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mnist_cnn_model_api.py", line 348, in <module>
    validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1596, in fit_generator
    callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 76, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
  File "/home/dominik/keras/mnist/my_functions.py", line 737, in on_epoch_end
    current_ist = current_is.eval()
  File "/home/dominik/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 575, in eval
    return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
  File "/home/dominik/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3633, in _eval_using_default_session
    return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
  File "/home/dominik/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/dominik/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 964, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/dominik/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1014, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/dominik/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1034, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype float
     [[Node: input_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
     [[Node: strided_slice_1/_1 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_6_strided_slice_1", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op u'input_1', defined at:
  File "mnist_cnn_model_api.py", line 113, in <module>
    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1198, in Input
    input_tensor=tensor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1116, in __init__
    name=self.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 309, in placeholder
    x = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/home/dominik/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1587, in placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/home/dominik/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 2043, in _placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/home/dominik/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/dominik/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2240, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/dominik/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1128, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype float
     [[Node: input_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
     [[Node: strided_slice_1/_1 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_6_strided_slice_1", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

I need this placeholder in line 113 - it doesn't make troubles when using Keras without any tensorflow session. But as soon as I am trying to use a tensorflow session (in order to use .eval() for transforming the tensor into numpy.ndarray) my code explodes...

I appreciate your help!

Comment: please show us your code, all this error is saying is that you didn't specify a value for a placeholder, so the Tensor can not be evaluated. You should do it like this `sess.eval(variable, feed_dict={input_1:[1,2,3]}`

Comment: Thank you for your kind help! 
Now I understand what my problem is and I am sure that I can fix it without posting my code (which is huge and messy).

I tried to feed my placeholder with some data following your advice. 
Unfortunately, an error occurrs: 
" AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'eval' ".


(Today I have just upgraded from tensorflow 0.12.1 to r1.0)